# I cant use Angular Devtools to debug web application

Tags: angular

I would like to debug my frontend application with Angular DevTools extension, but when I am running this app I am getting `Angular application running in production mode. We recommend using DevTools with apps in dev mode, running **ng serve**`.

So what I did is I disabled `enableProdMode()` call when running in dev env. And when app is started I am getting information that `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode`. But unfortunately DevTools are telling me that app is still in production mode, same error as above.

Maybe this is worth to say that I am running with TomEE, together with java code. So I am not using `ng serve` command.

Any idea how could I fix it? Or maybe is there other option to debug angular?

Comment: How are you launching the application? What dev tools are we using the chrome ones or any other?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara I tried to use `Angular DevTools` , on top it is build with maven, but inside of maven it is running exec with `ng build`. And after build it is run with tomee.